# How do I make sense of the calligraphic characters for 六波羅坂東寺会戦?

Tags: translation, meaning, readings

[image: title cartouche]

Hi

Can anyone assist by shedding light on the way that hiragana/kanji characters have been historically used in this 1850’s title cartouche? The catalogue raisonné for the artist simply records the work as: *Rokuhara han Tōji kwaisen*, and it is usually seen translated as *The Fight at the Eastern Temple, Rokuhara in Kyōto*, though there is no actual mention of the word Kyōto in the title.

Might the title translate as *The Battle at Tōji in the Domain of Rokuhara*? My best transcription of the Japanese characters is 六波羅坂東寺会戦, or 六はら坂とち[とぢ/とじ?]会戦. My inclusion of alternative hiragana in square brackets will be obvious in a moment (see point no.4).

In trying to make sense of the characters I have a few observations and questions.

1. It is difficult for me to read because characters are written in a calligraphic form that is--as I would describe it--an ‘intermediate’ style between hiragana and kanji. For instance, the second character *ha* は is derived from 波, and the third character *ra* ら is derived from 羅, constituting part of the word “Rokuhara.” Likewise, I think the fifth character *to* と is derived from 東, written in an intermediate form, forming part of the word *Tōji* (東寺).
2. The first three characters of the title can be read as “Rokuhara”; two of these are in sōsho, if my understanding of that word is correct. Rokuhara (六はら or 六波羅) was a south-eastern district in Kyōto that functioned as the Kyōto headquarters for deputies of the Kamakura shogunate.
3. The fourth character appears to be a cursive form of the kanji *han* 坂. The usual kun reading of 坂 is *saka*, meaning a “hill” or “slope.” References seem to indicate that the Goon reading is *ben* べん or *hon* ほん; the Kan’on reading is *han* はん; the Kan’yōon reading is *ban* ばん; and the Kun reading is *saka* さか. The title does not appear to make sense if the meaning is “slope,” so I wonder if *han* 坂 is being used phonetically in substitution for the character *han* 藩, a Daimyo’s “domain” in the Edo Period; a precursor to current prefectures. This is why I questioned whether part of the title would be read as “the domain of Rokuhara.” Does anyone have observations on *han* being read phonetically (in the context of ateji or man'yōgana)? Is this far-fetched?
4. My big question is in relation to the word *Tōji* (東寺). The fifth character *to* と is derived from 東, and is written in an intermediate form, however, it looks like the sixth character is a ち hiragana character, which would be pronounced *chi*. For it to be pronounced *ji* it should, I'd have thought, be written as ぢ or じ. The kanji 寺 can have a Goon reading *ji* じ, a Kan’on reading of *shi* し, and a Kun reading of *tera* てら; chiefly, a Buddhist temple. I have not been able to find an old cursive form of じ that looks anything similar to the form ち as written in this cartouche. Can anyone shed light on this? I’m confused by this, as Tōji (東寺, literally "East Temple", first known as Kyō-ō-gokoku-ji, 教王護国寺, “The Temple for the Defense of the Nation by Means of the King of Doctrines”) makes absolute sense in the context of the image, and being in Rokuhara.
5. Finally, there are the characters 会戦, read as *kaisen* for “battle,” but also written in an older form as *kwaisen*. I assume I have these right?

Any observations appreciated.

[image: Kuniyoshi print]

Comment: drooozeさんの疑問あるいは指摘を受けて検討した結果、新しい回答を用意することができました。日本語での回答で申し訳ありません。

Comment: I added the English translation to my second answer.

Answer (score 4):

## English

What is the character at the part of "?" in "六波羅？東寺合戦" written in a cursive or semi-cursive style that is considered to be the title of the battle picture placed on the upper right of the picture presented by the questioner?
And, what is the meaning of the entire title, if the character becomes obvious?

Since droooze's comment as "there is the remaining problem that the right side of the character looks more like「攵」 than 「反」. Have another look at all the calligraphic examples of 「坂」 given on this page; in all cases, the component 「厂」 is clearly written" became a valid inspiration, I challenged to solve the above two questions again.

As a result of my investigation, I obtained certain results, so I'm going to post a new answer here.

In the result of examination by those people participating in this question including "me", "?" has been supposed to be a kanji "坂 *slope* or *hill*" or "攻 *attack*" so far.

In order to clarify the character of "?" I did the work of the procedure shown below.
(1) At first, I collected kanjis having the same "偏 (へん) *the part of the left side of a kanji*" as that 坂 or 攻 has.
Next I collected kanjis having the same "旁 (つくり) *the part of the right side of a kanji*" as that they have.
The 偏 of them are "土" and "工", and the 旁 of them are "反" and "攵".

The kanjis collected as a result of the above work are as follows.
「土」：増、地、壇、均、坑、坪、塚、埋、坂
「工」：攻、巧、功、項、恐 （Note: Though "工" in "恐" is not 偏 of the kanji, I collected it because there are few kanjis that have "工" as 偏.）
「反」：飯、版、板、阪、販、坂
「攵」：攻、放、枚、教、牧、数、敷

I examined the shape in a cursive or semi-cursive style of each collected kanji.
I used "Stroke Order / Writing Character Dictionary for Writing Beautiful Characters" written by Kenji Emori, Published by Sanseido in order to examine the shapes.

The summarizing result of shapes in a cursive or semi-cursive style of the collected kanjis is shown in the figure below.
Looking at the figure, I could see the following things about the character expressed by "?"

- Judging about "土" and "工" as 偏 （へん） or the part of the left side of a kanji, it is "土". The reasons for this judgment are as follows.
  Basically, the first stroke (horizontal line), the second stroke (vertical line) and the third stroke (horizontal line) of "工" are continued in a cursive or semi-cursive style, which makes the shape like "乙 (おつ)" in kanji or "Z" in English. In this case, there is no protrusion on the first stroke (horizontal line), while when you see 偏 or the part of the left side of the character shown by "? ", the first and second strokes are separated, and the tip of the second stroke is popping out on the first stroke as you can see well.
- Judging about "反" and "攵" as 旁 (つくり) or the part of the right side of a kanji, it is "攵" judging from the collected shapes shown in the figure below.

[image]

If you deduce the character of "?" based on the above survey results, it will be neither "坂" nor "攻" which had originally been thought, but "**坆**" composed of "土" as 偏 (へん) and "攵" as 旁 (つくり).

Here, many Japanese including me are in great trouble. That's because the word "坆" is a simple character at the first sight but we have never seen it before so we don't even know how to read it.
Therefore, I looked up the character of "坆" on the Internet. As a result, the following facts were found out.

[Dictionary 1：ウイキまとめ](https://wikimatome.org/wiki/%E5%9D%86)

> **坆**
> 《音読み》
> （１）バイ《ピンイン》(méi)
> （２）フン《ピンイン》(fén)
> 《意味》
> （一）梅に同じ。
> （二）墳に同じ。
> **《日本語での特別な意味》せめる。▽攻の誤字。**

[Dictionary 2：【辞典・用語】［漢字林］「土部」](http://ksbookshelf.com/DW/Kanjirin/Kanjirin33.html)

> **【坆】**
> 土3+4=総画数7 U+5746 [フン、ブン、ホン、ボン/] 【墳坟】［土ノ一メ又攵坆］
> 　①土を丸く盛り上げて造った墓。ほぼ平らか比較的低い土盛りのものは「墓」
> 　②土を高く盛り上げたところ、堤防
> 　③丸く盛り上がった土
> 　④「三坆（さんぷん）」、伏羲・神農・黄帝の書、但し異説あり
> 　注解：いずれも「丸く盛り上がったさま（賁）」をいう

[Dictionary 3：漢典](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/5746.htm)

> ● **坆**
> méi
> ◎ 古同“梅”。
>
> ● **坆**
> fén
> ◎ 古同“[坟(⇐墳)](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/575F.htm)”。
> English
> a grave, tomb

Comprehensively looking at the definitions of three dictionaries, we can see the following things about "坆".

- Although there is a possibility that it is used in Japanese, it is basically a Chinese character.
- It has two kinds of meanings: an old character representing "梅 *plum*" and an old character representing "墳 *mound*".
- The meaning of 墳 is a grave or a tomb in English, but it is not a tomb in the plain graveyard but a grave with mound. It may be good to image the old tumulus or 古墳 (こふん).
- There is a difference in pronunciation depending on meanings: the pronunciation in the case of "梅" is バイ (méi), and the pronunciation in case of "墳" is フン (fén).
- In Chinese there are only two meanings of "坆" written above, but in Japan there is a case where it is wrongly used by making a mistake in writing "土" in place of "工" when writing "攻" meaning "to attack".
  Moreover, having a clear description like what is written in Dictionary 1 can be inferred that there have been quite a few mistakes of this kind in Japanese.

Let's go back to the original subject of "六波羅？東寺合戦". If you apply "坆" to the part of "?", the title becomes  "六波羅**坆**東寺合戦".
Based on the meanings of the Dictionaries on "坆", there seems to be no interpretation of "梅 *plum*" here, so the following two interpretations are possible.

> (A) 六波羅**攻**東寺合戦
> (B) 六波羅**墳**東寺合戦

For (A), there are three possible interpretations:
(A-1) A battle where The Rokuhara Army (= Kamakura Shogunate Army) attacked Toji-temple
(A-2) A battle, the battlefield was the area around Toji-temple, where The anti-Shogunate Army was attacked by The Rokuhara Army (= Kamakura Shogunate Army)
(A-3) A battle, the battlefield was the area around Toji-temple, where The Rokuhara Army (= Kamakura Shogunate Army) was attacked by The anti-Shogunate Army

We can easily understand that (A-1) is not a correct interpretation, because Toji-temple was one of the bases of Rokuhara-Tandai or 六波羅探題 that was the administrative agency established in Kyoto by the Kamakura Shogunate.
The next, we have to select the correct interpretation from (A-2) and (A-3). If this battle was the part of decisive ones of The Genkō War (元弘の乱 Genkō no Ran) that was a civil war in Japan which marked the fall of the Kamakura Shogunate, the answer is definitely (A-3).

> As the result, "六波羅攻東寺合戦" is read as "六波羅[攻]｛ぜ｝（め）東寺（之）合戦{かっせん}" meaning "A battle at Toji-temple attacking The Rokuhara Army (by The anti-Shogunate Army)".

As for (B), I would conclude that it is not the title of the picture of the battle presented by the questioner.
Apart from the conclusion for (B), the location of Rokuhara had been very closely related to "墳 *grave* or *tomb*" before the "Rokuhara-Tandai 六波羅探題" was established by Kamakura Shogunate there.
I'll omit the further explanation here, but if you are interested in the information about it, I recommend you to read the answer in Japanese.

## 日本語

質問者が提示した合戦の絵の右上に記載された絵の題名と思われる行書体あるいは草書体で書かれた「六波羅？東寺合戦」の内、「？」の部分の文字は何であるか、また、その文字が明白になった場合、題名全体の意味は何かというテーマに再度挑戦し、調査の結果、一定の成果が出たので新たに回答を提示する。

「？」の部分はこれまでの検討の結果では、「坂」あるいは「攻」という漢字ではないかということになっている。

「？」の文字を明確にするために以下に示す作業を行った。
（１）
「坂」または「攻」の「偏（へん：漢字の左側の部分）」と「旁（つくり：漢字の右側の部分）」の内、「土（つちへん）」と「工（たくみへん）」を「偏（へん）」として持っている漢字を調べる。次に「反（部首としての名称はない）」と「攵（のぼく / ぼくづくり）」を「旁（つくり）」として持っている漢字を調べる。
調べた漢字は以下のとおりである。

- 「土」：増、地、壇、均、坑、坪、塚、埋、坂
- 「工」：攻、巧、功、項、恐（なお「恐」の「工」は「たくみつくり」ではないが「工（たくみつくり）」の漢字が少ないので加えた）
- 「反」：飯、版、板、阪、販、坂
- 「攵」：攻、放、枚、教、牧、数、敷

（２）
調べた漢字の行書体および草書体の字形を調べる。
書体の字形には「きれいな字を書く 筆順・書き文字字典」江守賢治著（三省堂）を用いる。
字形を調べた結果をまとめたものを下図に示す。
図を見ると「？」の文字に関して次のことが分かる。

- 「へん」の「土」と「工」については「土」である。
  「工」は行書体、草書体ともに基本的に一画目（横棒）、二画目（縦棒）から三画目（横棒）までが続いた字形になり、漢字の「乙｛おつ｝」あるいは英語の「Z」のような形になる。従って、最初の横棒の上に突起が出ない。実際に「？」の文字の「へん」を見ると、一画目と二画目とが離れており、二画目の縦棒の先端が一画目の横棒の上に飛び出していることがよくわかる。
- 「つくり」の「反」と「攵」については「攵」である。
  これについては、列記した書体の「つくり（漢字の右側の部分）」を見ると明白である。

[image]

以上の調査結果に基づいて「？」の文字を推論すると、当初思っていた「坂」でも「攻」でもなく「土（つちへん）」に「攵（のぼく / ぼくづくり）」で構成された「**坆**」という文字であることが分かる

ここで、私を含めた多くの日本人は大変困ることになる。それは、「坆」という文字は見た目には簡単な文字であるが、これまで見たことも、またどう読むのかも知らないからである。

そこで、「坆」という文字をインターネットで調べた。その結果、以下に示すようなことが分かった。

[文献１：ウイキまとめ](https://wikimatome.org/wiki/%E5%9D%86)

> **坆**
> 《音読み》
> （１）バイ《ピンイン》(méi)
> （２）フン《ピンイン》(fén)
> 《意味》
> （一）梅に同じ。
> （二）墳に同じ。
> 《日本語での特別な意味》せめる。▽攻の誤字。

[文献２：【辞典・用語】［漢字林］「土部」](http://ksbookshelf.com/DW/Kanjirin/Kanjirin33.html)

> **【坆】**
> 土3+4=総画数7 U+5746 [フン、ブン、ホン、ボン/] 【墳坟】［土ノ一メ又攵坆］
> 　①土を丸く盛り上げて造った墓。ほぼ平らか比較的低い土盛りのものは「墓」
> 　②土を高く盛り上げたところ、堤防
> 　③丸く盛り上がった土
> 　④「三坆（さんぷん）」、伏羲・神農・黄帝の書、但し異説あり
> 　注解：いずれも「丸く盛り上がったさま（賁）」をいう

[文献３：漢典](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/5746.htm)

> ● **坆**
> méi
> ◎ 古同“梅”。
>
> ● **坆**
> fén
> ◎ 古同“[坟(⇐墳)](http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/575F.htm)”。
> English
> a grave, tomb

以上の３つの文献から「坆」について次のことが分かる。

- 一部日本語で使われている可能性はあるが基本的に中国の文字である。
- 「梅」を表わす古い文字と「墳」を表わす古い文字の２種類の意味がある。
- 「墳」の意味は墓（英語ではgrave あるいは tomb）だが、平地の墓ではなく、土を盛った墓である。古墳をイメージすると良いのかも知れない。
- 発音に違いがあり、「梅」の場合の発音はバイ(méi)、「墳」を場合の発音はフン(fén)。
- 中国では「坆」の意味は以上の２つしかないが、日本では「攻める」の意味の漢字「攻」の「工（たくみへん）」の部分を誤って「土（つちへん）」にしてこの字になった例があるように読み取れる。しかも[文献１](https://wikimatome.org/wiki/%E5%9D%86)のような明確な記述があるということは、この誤字が結構あるものと推察できる。

質問者の提示した「六波羅？東寺合戦」に話を戻すと、「？」の部分に「坆」を当てはめて「六波羅**坆**東寺合戦」となる。

「坆」に関する文献の意味に基づくと、ここでは「梅」の解釈はないと思われるので、次の２つの解釈ができる。

> (A) 六波羅**攻**東寺合戦
> (B) 六波羅**墳**東寺合戦

(A)については、
(A-1)「六波羅軍（＝鎌倉幕府軍）」が「東寺」を攻める「合戦」という意味と、
(A-2)「六波羅軍（＝鎌倉幕府軍）」が攻めた「東寺の辺りを戦場とする合戦」、更に
(A-3)「六波羅軍（＝鎌倉幕府軍）」を攻めた「東寺の辺りを戦場とする合戦」
という３通りの解釈ができるように思う。
私は、(A-1)ではないと思う。その理由はこの合戦（1333年に後醍醐天皇による討幕運動「元弘の乱」）は「六波羅探題軍（すなわち鎌倉幕府軍）」と「後醍醐天皇を擁立する倒幕軍」との間の合戦ではあるが、「六波羅」と「東寺」との合戦ではない。何故なら、「東寺」は「六波羅探題が管理する拠点の一つ」であり、六波羅探題から見た「敵軍」ではないからである。従って、「東寺」はあくまでも「戦場」であって「倒幕軍」を意味するような「東寺軍」ではない。
次に、(A-2)と(A-3)とであるが、この合戦ではいずれがいずれを攻めたのかと考えると、明らかに(A-3)の「倒幕軍」が「六波羅軍（すなわち鎌倉幕府軍）」を攻めたである。

> 結果として、「六波羅**攻**東寺合戦」の読みは、「六波羅[攻]｛ぜ｝め東寺の合戦」となる。

(B)については、結論として質問者の提示した合戦の絵の標題ではないと判断する。以下に示すいくつかの資料から、「六波羅」の地が鎌倉幕府による「六波羅探題」が置かれる以前から「墳＝墓」と大変関係が深いことが分かる。仮に六波羅の地が「死者」、「葬場」あるいは「墓地」と関係が深いといえども、「墳」の意味で日本語の文字として認知されていない「坆」という文字を敢えて用いる理由もない。

[資料１：六波羅](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E6%B3%A2%E7%BE%85)

> 六波羅（ろくはら）は、京都の鴨川東岸の五条大路から七条大路一帯の地名。
> 《歴史》
> 天暦5年（951年）空也がこの地に西光寺を創建し、後に中信がこの寺を六波羅蜜寺（ろくはらみつじ）と改名したことから「六波羅」と呼ばれるようになったという。
> この地は洛中（京都の市街地の意味。東は高野川・鴨川から、西は西大路通までの地域）から京都の住民の **葬地であった鳥辺野（とりべの）** に入る際の入口にあたる事から、この他にも六道珍皇寺など沢山の寺院が建てられ、信仰の地として栄えた。

資料１にあるとおり、六波羅探題の置かれていた辺りは鴨川の東側であり、「鳥辺野あるいは鳥部野（とりべの）」と呼ばれる火葬場、古くは鳥葬・風葬場そして墓地へと続く入り口の土地であった。

[資料２：鳥辺野（鳥部野）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B3%A5%E8%BE%BA%E9%87%8E)

> 鳥辺野（とりべの）は、京都市の一地域を指す地域名。鳥部野、鳥戸野とも書く。平安時代以来の墓所として、北の蓮台野（れんだいの）、西の化野（あだしの）とともに京都の三大墳墓地をなしている。

資料２によると、鳥辺野の位置は明確でないと書かれているが、挙がっている候補地を見ると、清水寺から東大路通（東山通）の間の丘陵地帯と思われる。六波羅探題跡（ろくはらたんだいあと）に近い六波羅蜜寺の北を通る松原通を東に進んで東大路通を越えると清水寺に到着するので、六波羅は鳥辺野へ続く地域であったと推察できる。

[資料３：六波羅蜜寺、六道の辻](http://skipio.sakura.ne.jp/04Kyoto/Rokuharamitsu-ji.html)

> ＜六波羅蜜寺の創建＞
> 　六波羅蜜寺は平家全盛をさかのぼること200年前、天暦5年（951年）醍醐天皇の第二皇子・空也上人（903～972）によって開創された天台宗寺院。
> 　平安遷都以降の歴史のなかで幾多の戦乱は殺戮を繰り返し、また度重なる飢饉は弱者を餓死させ、京都は常におびただしい死者の巣窟でもあった。
>
> ＜六道之辻＞
> 　六波羅蜜寺に向かう角（西福寺の角）に「六道之辻」という石塔が立っている。六道とは、生前の善悪の行いによって導かれる冥界で、天上、人間、修羅、 鬼畜（畜生）、餓鬼、地獄のこと。
> 　その昔、「六道の辻」は鳥辺野の無常所（墓場、墓地のこと）の入口にあたり、現世と冥途（めいど。死者が行く暗黒の世界。あの世）との境の地であり、亡骸（なきがら。死体）はこの辻の向こう側に捨てられた。金のない民衆は埋められもせず、弔（とむら）われることもなく放置され、穏亡（おんぼう。火葬場において死者を荼毘（だび）に付（ふ）し、遺骨にする仕事に従事する作業員）たちによって運び捨て去られた。その死せる肉体は風雨に曝され、髑髏（ドクロ）となって**六波羅の野辺に転がっていた**。
> 　その骨を拾い、さまよえる魂を供養したのが六波羅蜜寺創建の空也上人。

[資料４：京都の三大風葬地「化野」「**鳥部野**」「蓮台野」](http://www.syasin.biz/page/heianhusoti/)

> ２、鳥部野（とりべの）
> 京都から山科大津へ向かう際に五条坂（東大路通から清水寺へ向かう参道の一つ）を上がっていくと左手に大きな墓地が見えます。かなり大きい墓地で子供の頃からちょっと不気味に思っていたのだが、その墓地一体は平安時代は鳥辺野（とりべの）と呼ばれる、化野（あだしの）、蓮台野（れんだいの）と並ぶ京都三大風葬地でした。当時庶民がお墓に埋葬されるという事はなく、死者は木に吊るしその肉を鳥に喰らわせる鳥葬・風葬を行っていました。「鳥」という字がついているのは鳥葬の地、「野」というのは野原、場所を意味しました。
> 化野の記事でも書いたように徒然草の七段でもここが火葬の地であった事が書かれています。
> （※徒然草は鎌倉時代でありそのころには火葬が一般的になっていました。）
> 今は京都一の観光名所となっている清水寺もその鳥辺野という風葬の地にあたる地で、清水寺は宝亀９年（778年）それらの霊を供養する為に音羽の滝の近くに社を建てたのが始まりという説もあります。本殿が高い所にあるのは、死者の匂いがあまりにも強い為であったといわれています。また「清水の舞台」が突き出しているのは死体を投げ捨てるためだったという説もあります。

資料４の中の墓地の写真は圧巻ですので是非ご覧ください。京都市内の夜景が見渡せ、遠くに京都タワーも見えます。

Comment: Very thorough analysis, and you've confirmed what I suspected. Given that「坆」is not really a Japanese character in the sense of a variant of 「梅」or「墳」, wouldn't you say that 「《日本語での特別な意味》せめる。▽攻の誤字」is the most likely explanation? There is otherwise no reason to put a Chinese-only character in a piece of Japanese art. In any case, interpreting「坆」as「攻」fits in perfectly with why the English translation didn't include a reference to「坂」or something else in the position of that character. My only quibble is that「文献１：ウイキまとめ」doesn't include literature examples of where「坆」as「攻の誤字」has appeared.

Comment: @droooze: 疑問を放置しないdrooozeさんの熱心な探求心のお陰で「坆」という文字を見つけることができました。ありがとうございます。ところで、「文献１：ウイキまとめ」で「攻の誤字」の例としてＯＰの提示した「六波羅？東寺合戦」が使われないのは特に疑問（quibble）ではないと思います。理由として、この絵と遭遇しなかった。また、もし遭遇していても、草書体の解読がうまく出来ず私と同じように「坂」と読んだからだと思います。

Comment: @mackygoo: Apologies for the delay responding. When you first submitted in Japanese, I went through all your text and the website links, made notes, and did some further research. As previously discussed, the subject of the print is in The Taiheiki: The authorities at Rokuhara divided their 60,000 horsemen: one force was sent to the Department of Shrines to defend against Lord Ashikaga, one to Tōji to defend against Akamatsu, and one sent to secure Takeda and Fushimi. Akamatsu Enshin advances on Tōji Temple with 3,000 horsemen. Norisuke orders his men to break up the barricade...

Comment: ... there was a network of stakes, ropes, and branch barricades, as well as a moat more than thirty feet wide... The attackers hesitate to leap into the water, but Mega no Magosaburō Nagamune crosses the moat, leaps up from the bank, seizes a support jutting out four or five inches from the wall, and pulls it. The wall collapses, bringing down with it dirt from the moat, which had been piled on top to mountainous heights of ten or twenty feet...

Comment: “Upon seeing what had happened, the defenders released a fast and furious flight of arrows, thicker than falling raindrops, from more than 300 lookouts on top of the tile-capped earthern wall. Nagamune bent back the arrows lodged in his helmet wings and armor skirts, dashed under the main gate, and stood wrathfully gnawing his upper lip in front of the two guardian deities, his swordtip touching the ground. It was hard to tell which of the three figures was Nagamune and which were the Two Kings.” It is this point in the battle that is represented by Kuniyoshi.

Comment: “The main gate is endangered!” shout the 10,000 Rokuhara warriors stationed at Tōji, Nishihachijirō, Hari-no-kōji, and Karahashi, who were chased back toward the Shichijō riverbed . At this point the Hōjō adherents took refuge in the Rokuhara stronghold. The victorious pursuers (50,000 horsemen), consolidated their forces, besieged the stronghold, and burned its entrance. All said, there appear to be few examples of musha-e with Tōji as the subject: the Kuniyoshi image, and an Okumura Masanobu (奥村政信) print, untitled, c. 1710, showing Mega Magosaburō Nagamune at Tōji next to a guardian king.

Comment: That said, there are a number of C19th prints depicting the battles at Rokuhara, either the Heiji Rebellion in 1160, or the Genkō War in 1333. Given your provocations, I checked all the prints I could find with ‘Rokuhara’ in the title to see if 坂 or 坆 (the Chinese character, however strange) had been used in conjunction with 六波羅,  however every image I found used 六波羅 by itself; no threads. In this regard, the miswriting of 坆 when it should have been 攻 is logical, re: ‘Dictionary 1’, though as @droooze notes, it doesn’t cite examples. Perhaps we should add this example to the dictionary page!

Comment: B. W. Robinson, _Kuniyoshi: The Warrior-Prints,_ Cornell University Press, 1982, is effectively the catalogue raissonné for Kuniyoshi’s musha-e. _Rokuhara han Tōji kwaisen_ is catalogued as T270. As with all of the catalogue entries, the title is written in rōmaji—not given in Japanese characters—followed by a description, not a translation: “The fight at the Eastern Temple, Rokuhara, Kyoto (1333) defended by the Hōjō [... etc.].” Likewise at the Kuniyoshi Project (online). Prints on the private market are titled _The fight at the Eastern Temple, Rokuhara, in Kyoto,_ echoing this description.

Comment: As previously noted, the only other place I have seen the print listed is the British Museum (Accession No.: 1907,0531,0.636.1-3), and once again the title is not recorded in kanji/kana, simply in rōmaji: _Rokuhara-zaka Toji gosen_. Surely there are copies of the print in Japanese public collections, but I have not found any so far using online catalogues and databases. Anyway, my point is this: from my research to date, no Western museum has recorded the title in kanji/kana, and the reference to 'han' and 'saka'/'—zaka' has been on the record, unchallenged, since 1982 if not earlier.

Comment: In this regard—and without wanting to sound too full of hubris—this conversation thread, and yours and droooze's contributions on the Japanese characters have added something significant to scholarship in this area. It should not be underestimated... nor under appreciated from my perspective.

Comment: @musha: Through the comments of yours with abundant content, I understand that I could make a little contribution to the historical truth with droooze's serious attitude not allowing compromise and my little knowledge about Japanese characters. I want to show my respect to your attitude of serious quest for fact and also I am glad that I could study 六波羅探題 together with you.

Comment: @musha and mackygoo, I found the examples of the usage of 坆 as 攻. The GlyphWiki entry for **坆** (http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u5746) notes several Japanese dictionaries which list it as an entry, among them 大漢和辭典 and 和製漢字の辭典. I had a look at the entry for 坆 in 和製漢字の辭典 (http://ksbookshelf.com/nozomu-oohara/WaseikanjiJiten/WaseikanjiJiten_33.html), and this is what it says: 「せめる」は、国訓。〔読み〕 せめらる せめる。『寛元本字鏡集』に「攻歟 セメラル」、『篇目次第』に「セメラル 无玉」、『音訓篇立』に「セメラル セメラク」とある。。『寛元本字鏡集』・『篇目次第』・『音訓篇立』のものは「攻」の誤字であると考えられ、
「せめる」は、国訓といえる。I don't have access to these resources, so I cannot check further.

Answer (score 3):

写真の掛け軸（？）は「六波羅坂東寺**合**戦」と書かれています。「会戦」ではなく「合戦（かっせん/がっせん）」です。

- 全て<del>草書</del>行書に近い<del>行書</del>草書の漢字で書かれており、平仮名はありません。
- 「六波羅」は京都の鴨川東岸の五条大路から七条大路一帯の地名。現在の京都市東山区松原通り付近の地名です。
- <del>「六波羅坂東寺合戦」は「六波羅合戦」と言われているもので、平安時代末期の平治元年12月9日（1160年1月19日）に発生した後に平治の乱（へいじのらん）と呼ばれる政変の中の代表的な合戦です。</del>
- 「東寺」が「教王護国寺」を指すかどうか定かではありませんが、「坂」は、松原通りを東に進んで東山通りを横切ると清水寺辺りに向かうことになり、結局東山の裾野｛すその｝として坂になっておりますので、その辺りの地形を指しているのかも知れません。

[image]

Comment: Terrific chart you have uploaded/put together! Is it from a particular publication, or did you write these and composite yourself? It has reminded me of the gyōsho/sōsho references (which I had forgotten about) in James Self and Nobuko Hirose's **Japanese Art Signatures: A Handbook and Practical Guide**, Floating World Editions, 2003 (2005). Quite a useful publication re deciphering names and common adjuncts to signatures... that said, your chart with progressively cursive examples is 天の恵み.

Comment: @musha: 上記のchartは三省堂「きれいな字を書く　筆順・書き文字字典」（江守賢治著）から一文字ずつ引用して見やすいように編集しました。「六波羅坂東寺合戦」は明らかにすべて漢字だと思います。

Comment: Best resource I can find on the web, at least in English, is (https://archive.org/details/elementsofsosho00pigg). _The Elements of Sōsho_: Piggott, F. S. G. (Francis Stewart Gilderoy), 1883-1966: Publication date 1913: Publisher Yokohama, Kelly & Walsh. It can be downloaded as a PDF, which is quite handy.

Comment: @musha: The Elements of Sōsho拝見しました。部首ごとに丁寧に説明した本は初めて見ました。私は書道をしますが、大変役立つように思いました。あ‌​りがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

Speaking purely from the view from Chinese calligraphy, these are all valid ways to write Chinese characters, and thus the title indeed contains no hiragana as the other answer mentioned. I'll list some of the more difficult-to-comprehend ones:

1. **波**, example from Tang Dynasty 懷仁's《集王羲之聖教序》

[image]

2. **羅**, two examples: First from Sui Dynasty 智永's《真草千字文》, second from Song Dynasty 黃庭堅's《李白憶舊遊詩卷》:

[image]

3. と is not derived from **東**, as this Gyosho/Sosho style of writing 東 has been around for centuries in East Asia. Simplified Chinese even made the Gyosho/Sosho version official: **东**
4. **寺**, example from Ming Dynasty 韓道亨's《草訣百韻歌》:

[image]

5. As the other answer mentioned, you should interpret the 7th character as **合**. **会** is actually *already* a Gyosho/Sosho form codified into Kaisho, and was actually properly written as the Kyujitai form **會** before the Japanese promulgation of the Toyo Kanji list in 1946. Note that the bottom portion of the 7th character doesn't look like **云** anyway; a calligraphic example of 会/會 would look more like example on the left, taken from Ming Dynasty 祝允明's《行草牡丹賦》, while 合 looks more like something on the right, taken again from Tang Dynasty 懷仁's《集王羲之聖教序》:

[image]

As a final note, **と** comes from a cursive version of **止**, and **ち** comes from a cursive version of **知**; see [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%B3%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D#.E6.AD.B4.E5.8F.B2).

Comment: Thanks @droooze. Highly informative, and humbling. I have obviously gone down a rabbit hole where my novice status shows. You make note that と is not derived from 東, rather, from a cursive version of 止, and ち comes from a cursive version of 知. I am interested in late Edo musha-e, and often find myself trying to make sense of titles that have calligraphic/cursive elements (when titles may not be provided, or the translations are overly interpretative), and I am trying to learn from a plethora of references, largely online. ...[cont.]

Comment: One of those sites, in the context of these cursive versions, has been (http://www10.plala.or.jp/koin/koinhentaigana.html#si)... so all my original questions and confusions aside, it's how I managed to 'deduce' that the characters were/might be 波羅坂東寺会戦, even if the 会 should have been 合. The site shows hiragana characters and the kanji connected to them, including と and 東. Going on my earlier correspondence, have I incorrectly understood how to refer to this table? Can you recommend a book in English on this area that will be informative, with the many such varieties illustrated? best...

Comment: No, you haven't misunderstood. The forms in these tables are called Hentaigana (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hentaigana); the modern form of hiragana is due to a spelling reform instituted around 1900, which made all of the hiragana variants you see in the table, bar the ones used in modern spelling, obsolete. This means, for example, that one historical hentaigana variant representing the syllable 'to' looks like 东 and is derived from 東, but と is the 'official' hiragana variant used nowadays, and is not derived from 東.

Comment: Hiragana pre-1900 may appear as one of the Hentaigana variants instead of the current official kana. When reading Japanese calligraphy, you should expect short sequences of characters (e.g. titles) to be very Kanji-heavy, with hiragana scarcely appearing at all. Indeed, even particles like の may not even appear, or be replaced by 之, which is the Classical Chinese equivalent. In longer Japanese calligraphic texts, there will be hiragana, but as with Chinese cursive calligraphy, to correctly read such pieces you have to (perhaps ironically) already know what the piece says beforehand.

Comment: OK. So, in the context of the chart I linked to, and the notes you’ve made, hentaigana ("variant kana") can derive from many different kanji, and are defined as “obsolete or nonstandard hiragana.” If I come across a hentaigana, my default position should be to type it up as a kanji character, and only use the reference to the hiragana to assist, if necessary, understanding what the syllable/sound will be. Would that be your best suggestion/guiding principle?  (... cont.)

Comment: When I see ノ, 乃, or 之, I have always typed them in as such (to be as true to the text I am looking at), but seeing other simple variants for ‘no’  (such as F571 and F572 in the chart (http://www10.plala.or.jp/koin/koinhentaigana.html#no))—especially in a narrative cartouche with a lot of hiragana—I have tended to write it in as の, however, if I defer to that principle, I should have recorded it as 能, recording it in rōmaji as 'no' rather than 'nō' . Yes/no?

Comment: Your link: “Hiragana originate in man'yōgana,.. kanji were used to write sounds without regard to their meaning.” So, back to my original question about ‘han’ 坂 in the title. @mackygoo 's table shows the ‘han’ in the title is sōsho, but—correct me if I’m wrong—this doesn’t mean it is hentaigana. Given the image/period it was printed, do you think ‘han’ 坂 is being used phonetically for ‘han’ 藩, “domain”? Area near Tōji temple appears (google street view) to be ‘flattish’—not on a slope, hill, ‘saka’. The British M. writes ‘zaka’, yet Robinson's raissoné of Kuniyoshi records ‘han’. Any thoughts?

Comment: The standard Japanese practice for transcribing classical Japanese texts converts hentaigana into the modern kana forms. Only manyogana-type texts are transcripted with kanji. As for 坂, I don't think it is phonetically replaceable by 藩; such replacements normally have historical precedence and will actually be listed in dictionaries. I'm going to offer a potentially disagreeable opinion, which is that the artist miswrote 坂 but meant 攻 (attack) instead; their Gyosho/Sosho forms actually look very similar, with only a slightly different left hand side component.

Comment: 六波羅攻東寺合戰 actually makes much more sense, and avoids a contrived explanation involving a location named 六波羅坂 which does not really exist as a proper noun.

Comment: Insight appreciated: I am all for ‘disagreeable opinions’! Your hypothesis: 六波羅坂東寺合戰 / ‘Rokuhara [han/saka] Tōji kassen’ / ‘The Battle at Tōji, Rokuhara’ might have been intended as 六波羅攻東寺合戰 / ‘Rokuhara semeru Tōji kassen’ / ‘The attack on Tōji at the battle of Rokuhara’. There is a Yoshitoshi print where the kanji 檀 in 'Dan-no-ura' is not the usual 壇. It's not known if this is an error on Yoshitoshi's part, or a subtle visual pun. (I.e. 八島檀[壇]之浦合戰義經八艘飛之圖.) So it’s not impossible, I'm very much open to the idea! Do you have a sōsho/gyōsho example of 攻 per your Chinese calligraphic examples?

Comment: @mackygoo has made two comments in the section below, regarding the use of 坂. Would you have any position on this?

Answer (score 1):

Sōsho-tai examples of semeru versus saka, per @droooze comments:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unable to post image in comments, but see this: http://www.shufazidian.com/shufa6/4ac514813ea7f39b47662d455480220c3.jpg

Comment: I'm thinking of the examples in the first column, second- and third-to-last characters. The first character in the first column even made the same "mistake" of protruding the vertical stroke in the left hand component! Also, I think mackygoo's analysis of what 坂 means is the reasonable given that 坂 is the intended character.

Comment: 確かに「攻める」の「攻」と「坂」とは草書で書くと似ています。特に、文字の右側はほとんど同じになります。しかし文字の左側の「工」と「土」は絶対に違います。たとえ草書でも、「工」と「土」を区別して書かない人はいません。「六波羅攻東寺合戦」は意味がありそうで好都合に見えますが、このケースはありません。今私が考える「六波羅坂東寺合戦」の解釈は、「幕府軍東寺 之{の} 合戦」という意味で、英語で表現すると 'The Battle of Shogunate Army, called the Army of Rokuhara Hill/Slope, at Tōji' となります。

Comment: @mackygoo While I agree that your explanation is very likely, there is the remaining problem that the right side of the character looks more like「攵」than「反」. Have another look at all the calligraphic examples of 「坂」given on this page; in all cases, the component「厂」is **clearly** written. This is not the case in「六波羅X東寺合戦」; the last stroke of the left side joins to the top of the right side, and **you can actually see the gap** between the last stroke of the left side and the first stroke of the right side, indicating that the last stroke of the left side does not in fact double as the left of 反.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mackygoo. (Couldn't fit a reply into the comments section.) From what you have said (and my Japanese is really poor, my apologies), I need to change 会戦 to 合戦. It is interesting that you write "there is no hiragana" in the cartouche... Perhaps you or another poster might be able to shed light on the use of these cursive forms. Perhaps I misunderstand how these cursive forms are best described, and if they are closer to kanji or to hiragana, etc.

[image: ha][image: ra][image: to]

In terms of the actual battle and reference to Tōji, the image does not represent a skirmish at Rokuhara as part of the 1160 Heiji Rebellion that began with the siege of Sanjō Palace and concluded with Minamoto Yoshitomo's failed attack on the Rokuhara mansion, rather, the image I am looking at alludes to the Battle of Rokuhara on the twentieth day of June 1333—which was one of the decisive battles of the Genkō War—where Ashikaga Takauji turned on his former allies, sided with the Emperor Go-Daigo and drove the forces of the Shogunate out of their headquarters in Rokuhara. The print shows Mega Magosaburō Nagamune, Banshi Norisuke, and Ashikaga Takauji amongst others, so I know it is definitely the 1333 battle. The Taiheiki (太平記) makes specific reference to the battle of Rokuhara and Akamatsu Novice Enshin advancing on Tōji Temple with 3,000 horsemen. The army reached the the two-storied gate... The temple was protected by a solid wall made of excellent timbers five to nine inches square in size [...] extending from the Rashōmon foundation on the west to the hachijō riverbed on the east... etc. So I am confident that Tōji should be part of the title, only that I don't understand how to read the 'ji'. I am still a little confused about the 'saka'/slope reference, since most sources indicate that 'Han' should be part of the title. That said, your notes made me do some more checking and I note that the British Museum indicates the title should be written as 'Rokuhara-zaka Toji gosen'.

Comment: 「六波羅坂東寺合戦」がすべて漢字である映像を作成します。少々お待ちください。

Comment: 「六波羅坂東寺合戦」の読み方は「ろくはら-ざか とうじ かっせん」だと思います。合戦は「がっせん」とも「かっせん」とも読みますが、歴史上の戦いは「かっせん」と呼ばれているように思います。例えば「川中島の合戦」は「かわなかじまのかっせん」です。但し、「合戦」の直前の発音が「[寺]｛じ｝」と濁音ですので「がっせん」かもしれません。なお、British Museum の「ごうせん」という読み方は間違いだと思います。

Comment: ところで、「六波羅坂東寺合戦」が1160年の平治の乱ではなく、鎌倉幕府の滅亡につながる1333年の合戦であると納得した上での質問です。最初の質問の最後に提示された３枚の絵の「六波羅坂東寺合戦」は、実際にどこで戦われたのだと思いますか。京都東区五条から七条にかけての「六波羅」と呼ばれている辺りかそれとも京都南区九条にある東寺の辺りのいずれですか。

Comment: As you know「六波羅」には東に行くと坂がありますが、東寺の辺りには坂がない。私は「坂」を次の「東」と組み合わせて「[坂東]｛ばんどう｝」すなわち「関東 Kanto area」、更には、京都から見て関東にある鎌倉幕府を指している可能性を考えています。1160年の六波羅の合戦を「六波羅合戦」と呼んでいますが、それと区別するために、鎌倉幕府との合戦と言う意味の「坂東」を挿入して「六波羅坂東合戦」と呼んだ。しかし、この場合の「寺」の処理が困りますのでやはり間違った解釈かもしれません。

Comment: Before uploading my question, I also asked myself if ‘坂東寺’ might be 'bandō' (坂東) followed by 'ji' (寺), instead of 'han/saka' (坂) and 'tōji' (東寺). As you indicate, Bandō (坂東) is the old name of the Kantō region including Kamakura in Kanagawa prefecture. Could the title 六波羅坂東寺合戦 be read as ‘Rokuhara Bandō ji kaisen’ instead of ‘Rokuhara han Tōji kaisen’? My Japanese is not good enough to know if this works: you seem to indicate that the 'ji' is problematic. How would it translate into English: The battle at the temple in Rokuhara against the Bandō forces? I think it definitely reads 'tōji' (東寺).

Comment: Where is the east temple? I assumed that ‘東寺’ would be capitalised as Tōji, a proper noun, a place name, opposed to a general tōji that might signify any ‘eastern temple’ in Kyōto. In this regard, the temple would be near Mibu Dori and Kujo Dori. The Taiheiki (太平記) mentions the battle of Rokuhara and Akamatsu Novice Enshin advancing on Tōji Temple. It begins with: “An army led by an eastern warrior, Ashikaga Takauji, proclaims its loyalty to the exiled Emperor Go-Daigo and threatens the western headquarters of the Kamakura shogunate at Rokuhara, across the Kamo River from the capital. [...]

Comment: “The authorities at Rokuhara divided their 60,000 horsemen into three forces. One was stationed in front of the Department of Shrines to defend against Lord Ashikaga, one was dispatched to Tōji Temple to defend against Akamatsu, and one was sent north of Fushimi to secure Takeda and Fushimi, which were menaced by the advance of the Chigusa Lord Tadaaki.” I note that the Lyon Collection (http://woodblockprints.org/index.php/Detail/Object/Show/object_id/842) has a print titled “Mega Magosaburō Nagamune [妻鹿孫三郎長宗] at Battle of Tōji [束寺] (Temple).” So everything points to the Tōji Temple complex.

Comment: 私の日本語のコメントに丁寧な情報ありがとうございます。頂いた情報やインターネット等で探した情報を基に判断すると「六波羅坂東寺合戦」は1333年の鎌倉幕府倒幕につながる大きな合戦であって、多分次のような意味を表していると思います。現在の京都市南区九条にある東寺（教王護国寺とも言う）を守るために派遣された「六波羅 （探題）グループ」と赤松等の倒幕グループとの「東寺（周辺）」における「合戦」。東寺に派遣されたグループを東山裾野の「[坂]｛さか｝ slope」になぞらえて「六波羅坂 rokuhara-zaka」と呼んだ。なお、坂は単独では「さか」と読むが、「～坂」として使うときには「ざか」とも読まれる。全体としての読みは「ろくはらざか とうじ かっせん」。

Comment: The reason why I used 六波羅坂, which represents the name of a certain place, as the group of the Kamakura shogunate side is because there are cases in Japan where we use the name of a certain place in order to refer to a group which is located there or around the place. In its representative case, when we say "永田町 *Nagata-cho*" where the government agencies such as the Diet and government offices are located we mean to point to political circles by the word.

Comment: I understand what you are saying in English, but I have missed the subtlety/full explanation when you wrote in Japanese (my ability to translate is not good enough). I have looked everywhere on the web for a reference to '六波羅坂'  in kanji, or 'rokuhara-zaka' written in rōmaji, but can't find anything. How exactly does 坂 come to mean 'group/neighbourhood' instead of 'slope' in this instance? If I was writing the title '六波羅坂東寺合戦' in rōmaji you are saying it would be _Rokuhara-zaka Tōji kassen_ or _Rokuhara-zaka Tōji taisen_, but how would the title be written in English to make sense of 坂?

Comment: 六波羅は今でこそ土地の名前ですが、その当時は六波羅探題という役所の名称だったと思います。従って京都にいる鎌倉幕府勢力を指すのに六波羅探題があった場所の特徴を冠しても不思議でないような気がします。もし、六波羅探題の所在地に「池」があったら、「池のそばにいる六波羅探題一派/軍勢」という意味で「六波羅池」と呼んだかも知れません。その場合は「池のやつら」と馬鹿にして呼んだかもしれません。今度の場合は「坂のやつら」という意味合いです。

Comment: Hi @mackygoo. I've given much thought to your last posts, and undertaken further research. I understand that Rokuhara might refer to the geographic domain as well as the people/institution: there are the Rokuhara Tandai (六波羅探題), one speaks of the Rokuhara forces, etc. I think I understand your point about the Rokuhara men literally coming down ‘the slope’ from the Rokuhara district—the area falls within the modern Higashiyama District (東山区, Higashiyama-ku, created 1929) along the lower slopes of Kyoto's eastern mountains, so it is above the old central city of Kyōto and the Tōji temple... but

Comment: it is still frustrating to know how to reference the 坂 in  六はら坂东寺合戰 (Rokuhara-zaka Tōji kassen) in English. I do not believe that the current English title 'The Fight at the Eastern Temple, Rokuhara in Kyōto' that is written by art institutions is fully accurate, because it ignores the han/saka/-zaka, but I am stumped for an alternative title that doesn't sound clumsy or needs interpolation, e.g. 'The Battle at Tōji [against the forces from] Rokuhara Hill'. If you were tasked with the job of balancing the poetry/essence/meaning of the Japanese characters, how would you approach it in English?

Comment: 確かに「六波羅？東寺合戦」の「?」の文字の右側は「反」より「攵」に近いように見えます。しかし、その文字の左側は「工」ではなく「土」のように思えます。現在、「攻」「功」「巧」「項」「埋」「増」、「坂」「地」「均」「坑」「坪」「塚」、「板」「飯」「仮」「販」「版」「坂」、「放」「枚」「教」「牧」「数」「敷」などの漢字の草書の字形を調べておりますので少々お待ちください。　なお、私は今も「坂」を捨てきれず、「六波羅」「五条坂」などのキーワードで手掛かりを探しています。こちらもまとまったら情報を提供します。

Comment: [Breaking news]  If I honestly take the result of my examining cursive styles of some Kanjis, the character concerned is neither "坂" nor "攻" but "坆".
"坆" is not a Japanese character but a Chinese one, but there is a meaning of "墳 *grave / tomb*" and a comment with "it is sometimes incorrectly used instead of 攻 in Japanese language". Though 坆 is relatively easy to be understood when it means "攻", you can also understand 坆 as 墳 or grave/tomb somewhat reasonably, because 六波羅 had been deeply to do with the dead or graves/tombs. Details will be explained as another answer.